# plot list values against the list index

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of list in which each list contains some numbers, let's say

```
t = [[5,6,1],[4,6,33],[6,33,5,10],[1,2],[1,22,44,3]]
```

using python3 I would like to plot each list values against this particular list index, in the above example I should have x-axis from 1 to 3, y-axis from 1 to 50 with a mark on (1,5),(1,6),(1,1),(2,4),(2,6) ...

here is my code

```
x = list(range(3))
y = [[5,6,1],[4,6,33],[6,33,5,10],[1,2],[1,22,44,3]]


for i in range(len(x)):
    purchases = y[i]
    for j in range(len(purchases)):
        plt.scatter(x,purchases)
```

it plots the first two indices correctly then i get the error:

> x and y must be in the same size

output image

[image]

what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I think it's because your `x` list only have 3 elements and `y` 5. Both lists should have the same element size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need

```
y = [[5,6,1],[4,6,33],[6,33,5,10],[1,2],[1,22,44,3]]


for v in y:
    plt.scatter(range(len(v)),v)
```

which is basically to calculate the `range` of each value on the go, because your `y` list has different-sized lists inside it

[image]

---

If you want to set the *same x* for each index of `y` , then do

```
for i,v in enumerate(y):
    plt.scatter([i+1]*(len(v)),v)
```

*Notice that I've done `[i+1]` because the way you wrote it, seemed you wanted an index starting from 1*

[image]